# How to add a checkbox to registration and user profile?

Tags: user-registration, profiles

I need to add a privacy policy checkbox to user registration AND user profile (checkable and uncheckable at anytime in your user life). I was thinking there would be tons of plugins doing this, but I am searching for hours not finding anything suitable.

I could find how to add a checkbox programmatically to registration form (like [this](https://wpbrigade.com/add-privacy-policy-checkbox-registration-form/)) but not on the user profile. So how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add fields on user profile page,there are some [filters for displaying](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile) them and some [filters for saving](https://codex.wordpress.org/edit_user_profile_update) them and [another action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) for updating personal options.

Comment: Thank you, I add an extended version of the answer, just for people passing by, looking for code

Answer (score 5):

The extended answer...

```
// Add the checkbox to registration form
add_action( 'register_form', 'foo_add_privacy_policy_field' );
function foo_add_privacy_policy_field() { 
  ?>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo_privacy_policy" id="foo_privacy_policy" class="checkbox" style="float: left; height: 50px;" />
    <label for="foo_privacy_policy"><?php _e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ) ?>
    </label>
  </p>
  <?php
}

// Validate the checkbox value in the registration form so that it is required
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'foo_privacy_policy_auth', 10, 3 );
function foo_privacy_policy_auth( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
  if ( !isset( $_POST['foo_privacy_policy'] ) ) :
    $errors->add( 'policy_error', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please accept the privacy policy." );
    return $errors;
  endif;
  return $errors;
}

// Fill the meta 'foo_privacy_policy' with the value of the checkbox
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'foo_privacy_policy_save' );
function foo_privacy_policy_save( $user_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['foo_privacy_policy'] ) ){
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'foo_privacy_policy', $_POST['foo_privacy_policy'] );
  }else{
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'foo_privacy_policy', 'off' );
  }
}

// Add the checkbox to user profile home
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'foo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
function foo_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="foo_privacy_policy" id="foo_privacy_policy" class="checkbox" style="float: left; height: 50px;" <?php if(get_the_author_meta('foo_privacy_policy', $user->ID)=='on' ){ echo "checked"; } ?> />
    <label for="foo_privacy_policy"><?php _e( 'Privacy Policy', 'foo' ) ?>
    </label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_registration_privacy_policy', 11 );
function add_registration_privacy_policy() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy_reg', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
        'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
        'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => 'I\'ve read and accept the <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>',
    ));
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'validate_privacy_registration', 10, 3 );
function validate_privacy_registration( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['privacy_policy_reg'] ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'privacy_policy_reg_error', __( 'Privacy Policy consent is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```